# Android - Clearing ArcGIS objects from memory

Tags: android, garbage-collection, arcgis

I'm using ArcGIS in my Android project. The problem is that the map object is not cleared from memory when the Activity is finished and that's causing a memory leak and then an exception when starting many activities which contain maps.
How can I clear all these objects from the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Call `MapView.pause()` in your `Activity`'s `onPause()` method, and call `MapView.unpause()` in your `Activity`'s `onResume()` method:

```
@Override 
protected void onPause(){
    mMapView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override 
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.unpause();
}
```

See the [`MapView` JavaDoc](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html) for more information.